# How to create subprocess using exec in Typescript Class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, git, subprocess, exec

I would like to automate making MR in gitlab. Once a button is pressed in my React/Typescript UI, I'd like to run command-line code in my typescript class to clone a repo. However, when I try to use `exec` I always get this error: `TypeError: exec is not a function.`

**My Typescript Class:**

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

export class GitlabRepo {

    constructor(){
    }
    
    clone(){
        console.log("CLONE");

        exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
                return;
            }
            if (stderr) {
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        });
    }
    
    commit(message: string){
        console.log("COMMIT", message);
    }

    push(){
        console.log("PUSH");
    }
}
```

For now I am just trying to get some mock functionality of `ls -la` running. Ideally I'd replace those commands with `"git clone repo-here"`

Comment: Is this code being executed by the browser or by a Node server-side app?

Comment: The UI would be running on the browser. Does that make what I want to do impossible?

Comment: I really just want to automate Merge Requests.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript running in the browser does not have permission to execute processes. `child_process` is provided by Node, but not web browsers.

You have a few options to launch Git from React:

1. If you want to build a web app, then the web app must make HTTP calls to a server, and the server will call exec to launch Git.
2. If you want to use React but don't care if it's a web app, you could use [Ink](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink) to build a terminal app. A terminal app is executed by Node, so you have access to execute processes.